# search data from geoserver wms using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, openlayers

I am new to  Openlayers, and I am developing apps using Openlayers and Jquery mobile and for data layer I'm using Geoserver WMS. I got the code below from an Jquery mobile example, and my question is how can I change the search function to display data from a Geoserver WMS.

```
var selectedFeature = null;

var searchUrl ='http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&maxRows=10';
    searchUrl += '&name_startsWith=' + $('#query')[0].value;
    $.getJSON(searchUrl, function(data) {
        $.each(data.geonames, function() {
            var place = this;
            $('<li>')
                .hide()
                .append($('<h2 />', {
                    text: place.name
                }))
                .append($('<p />', {
                    html: '<b>' + place.countryName + '</b> ' + place.fcodeName
                }))
                .appendTo('#search_results')
                .click(function() {
                    $.mobile.changePage('#mappage');
                    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(place.lng, place.lat);
                    map.setCenter(lonlat.transform(gg, sm), 10);
                })
        .show();
    });
```

Comment: WMS returns raster data, ie, an image, only. If you are looked for search data, then you need to look into WFS. WFS can be quite complex, so you might be better off sticking with something which returns JSON, as in your example.

Comment: thanks for your reply, you have any example or code that i can refer?

Comment: i already make the php file, how i want to make my php file interact with that code?how im supposed to do?

Comment: As John pointed out, WMS only returns raster data. If you would like to query data of a WMS-Layer, you'll need to use the GetFeatureInfo-Request of WMS. There are examples for OpenLayers 2 and 3 online. Look at this for example: http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/getfeatureinfo.html

Comment: i already did but still not have luck

Comment: i have json file, need help, how i want to change the SearchURL using my json file?